# How can i set the title of UIButton in front of the UIButton image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I use `[button setImage:image forState:0];` to set a image to a UIButton.

Then I want the title of it using `[button setTitle:[titleArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:0];`.

But the image cover the title which I want to show in front of the image.

Any solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use setBackgroundImage:forState instead.  When you use the (foreground) image, you dont get to set a title.